# Если str_ireplace() не удовлетворяет условию php

Tags: php, текст, find

У меня есть код, в котором я сопоставляю слова через запятую с текстом, с помощью функции `str_ireplace()`:

```
$words = "word1, word2, word3";
$text = "This is word1 text word2";

if (str_ireplace(explode(', ', $words), '', $text) != $text) {
   /*Логика*/
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать обратную логику? Т.е. если ничего не будет найдено или сопоставлено.

`else {}` не работает.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$words = "word1, word2, word3";
$text = "This is word1 text word2";
$str = str_ireplace(explode(', ', $words), '', $text);
if ( $str != $text) {
   echo "Strings not equals!";
} else {
   echo "Strings is equals!";
}
```

Почему так работает, а как у Вас нет? Читаем мануал https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-ireplace

```php
 str_ireplace(
    array|string $search,
    array|string $replace,
    string|array $subject,
    int &$count = null
): string|array
```

Как видите возвращаемый тип `string|array` т.е по сути `mixed` без явного приведения к типу `string` интерпретатор не понимает какой же у Вас тип возвращается и не может сравнить корректно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!